# InAppSettingKit setHiddenKeys for Child Views

Tags: ios, iphone, inappsettingskit

it appears that setHiddenKeys isn't working for child views loaded through something like

```
    <dict>
        <key>File</key>
        <string>ChildView</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>CHILD_VIEW_TITLE</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSChildPaneSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
```

Any key specified in the target file is not iterated within the dataSource of IASK.

Any ideas how to have setHiddenKeys work throughout child views?

Thanks!

M

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed: https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/issues/167